# Image slider using viewPager. freeze while sliding

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, androidimageslider

I'm created app, which gets images from gallery, shows in VewPager and we can slide it. There only problem is that if the image size is more than 1mb, the slide freezes, lagging. If i add images in gallery 100-200kb, that not freeze. Any solution? Thanks.

Here the adapter.

```
public class PhotoPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ImageView imageView;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Bitmap> listOfAllBitmap = new ArrayList<>();

public PhotoPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    getAllShownImagesPath();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listOfAllImages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photopager, null);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photoView2);


    imageView.setImageBitmap(listOfAllBitmap.get(position));
    imageView.setRotation(90);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
    viewPager.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);
}

private void getAllShownImagesPath() {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data;
    String absolutePathOfImage;
    uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
        listOfAllBitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absolutePathOfImage));
    }

    cursor.close();
}
}
```

And here's the fragment.

```
public class ShowCamera2 extends BaseFragment{

private View mainView;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private PhotoPagerAdapter photoPagerAdapter;
private Button prev, next;
private TextView imageCount;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);

    prev = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.prevPhoto2);
    next = (Button) mainView.findViewById(R.id.nextPhoto2);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) mainView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    photoPagerAdapter = new PhotoPagerAdapter(this.getActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(photoPagerAdapter);

    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
        }
    });

    return mainView;
}
}
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you for reading.

Here the update.

```
public class PhotoPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ImageView imageView;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Bitmap> listOfAllBitmap = new ArrayList<>();

public PhotoPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    getAllShownImagesPath();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listOfAllBitmap.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photopager, null);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photoView2);


    imageView.setImageBitmap(listOfAllBitmap.get(position));
    imageView.setRotation(90);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
    viewPager.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);
}

private void getAllShownImagesPath() {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data;
    String absolutePathOfImage;
    uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        //listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
        listOfAllBitmap.add(decodeBitmapURI(context, absolutePathOfImage, 1000, 500));
    }

    cursor.close();
}

public Bitmap decodeBitmapURI(Context context, String uri, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri)), null, options);
        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, imageWidth, imageHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri)), null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
}
```

Comment: Try using picasso or ImageLoader and resize the bitmaps, according to height and width of ImageView

Comment: How can i resize the bitmaps?

Comment: And can i usng imageLoader get my images from gallery like here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Glide, and this helped me.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private ImageView imageView;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<>();

public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    getAllShownImagesPath();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listOfAllImages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photopager, null);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photoView2);

    Glide.with(context).load(listOfAllImages.get(position))
            .thumbnail(1f)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
    viewPager.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);
}

private void getAllShownImagesPath() {
    Uri uri;
    Cursor cursor;
    int column_index_data;
    String absolutePathOfImage;
    uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
        listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
    }

    cursor.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Picasso.with(mContext).
                    load(url) // from gallery load("file://" + url)
                    .centerCrop().placeholder(placeHolderRecource)
                    .resize(Utilities.dpToPx(100, mContext), Utilities.dpToPx(100, mContext)).into(imgView);


    public static int dpToPx(int dp, Context mContext)
        {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
            return px;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. In my adapter i have getAllShownImagesPath() method. This method gets the path of images from gallery. So how can i use this in Picasso? Thank you.

Comment: just do file:// + getAllShownImagesPath().get(i) and pass to load(x)

Comment: if possible attach a sample path

Answer (score 1):

Replace this linelistOfAllBitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(absolutePathOfImage));

with

listOfAllBitmap.add(decodeBitmapURI(context, Uri.parse(new File(absolutePathOfImage).toString()), 700, 350););

Check below solution for Loading Large Images, as android docs:

```
 public Bitmap decodeBitmapURI(Context context, Uri uri,int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        try {       
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, imageWidth, imageHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        return null;
    }






    public int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, i wrote it, but where to call decodeBitmapURI method?

Comment: Hi, i done something like this. The second parametr is uri, but my absolutePathOfImage in adapter is string. So i changed the second parameter to string and done Uri.parse(). Now i'm launching, there i see 8 images but the images are not visible. So it loads the images from gallery but not visible. If you want i can add the code.

Comment: Ok, wait a minute now i add the code in my question.

Comment: Just replace absolutePathOfImage in decodeBitmapURI method with Uri.parse(new File(absolutePathOfImage).toString())

Comment: I done like you said, but the image is not visible yet.